# Profit maximization given list of projects and list of sources needed to complete each project

Tags: combinatorics, maximize

We are given list of projects and cash rewards for project completion. Each project has a list of sources needed to complete the project. If we decide to buy a source, we need to pay the listed price once and we can use it for all projects. Each source can be required in more than one project. If we buy all necessary sources that project requires, the project is complete and we receive stated cash reward. We need to find an algorithm (not code) to maximize the profit.

I can think of one heuristics only.

First of all I go through all lines and check if there are any lines, that if I buy all the sources required to complete the project I have no loss of money (I either earn some money or have zero balance). If I find such line I buy all required sources.

But such line may or may not exists and I end up trying all possible subsets. I still think it could be solved in polynomial time. I can't think of any way how to apply some network flow algoritm. Any ideas?

Comment: This has two upvotes, but surely this is OT for SO. Recommend removal to some other board.

Comment: Can reward be used to buy sources?

Comment: Yes. It can be solved by network flows and Ford-Fulkerson algorithm.